# A subring of $\Bbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$ that is a integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I need to find a subring of $\Bbb{Z}[X]/(X^2)$ that is an integral domain.

My initial thought was the trivial subring consisting of only one element namely $0+(X^2)$ but my definition of integral domain requires the ring to have a $1$. So I am stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You were on the right track... except that the "trivial subring" in the context of rings with unity is the smallest subring generated by the element "1" (whatever is the unity element in that ring). This smallest subring with unity is the image of $\mathbb Z$ under the map that sends 1 (integer) to "1" (the unit in the ring). In your example, the image is all the constants, a subring of your ring that is in fact isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and therefore an integral domain.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand could you write down explicitly what the ring is? Are you saying the ring is just $(1)=\{1r:r\in \Bbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense in any ring. As a set, it is the additive group generated by the unit element of the ring. That is also automatically closed under the ring multiplication (because the associative law must hold in any ring), and it contains the 0 and 1 of the ring. It is the smallest subring with unit of the original ring, it is always a commutative ring even if the original ring was non-commutative, and it is a quotient ring of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So is the subring we are talking about just $\Bbb{Z}$ or is it $\Bbb{Z}+(X^2)$?

Comment: It is really $\mathbb Z + (X^2)$ if by that you mean the set of all cosets of constant polynomials. (I add that clarification because the notation is still slightly abusive - you are regarding $\mathbb Z$ as a subset of the polynomial ring - which is OK, you identify integers with constant polynomials.)

Comment: Actually, the ring with one element does have a multiplicative unit. It fails to be an integral domain because the definition of an integral domain requires $1 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

You know that $X$ can not be in the ring because $X^2=0$ in $Z[X]/\langle X^2 \rangle$. Therefore, exclude elements with $X$ in them. You are left with just the constants, so the subring that is an integral domain is simply $\Bbb{Z}$.

(Also, this isn't exactly relevant, but this ring is isomorphic to the [set of dual numbers with integer coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number).)